# Is the quantum NOT operation similar to the classical NOT operation?

Tags: quantum-information

$\renewcommand{ket}[1]{\left| #1 \right\rangle}$
**Classical NOT operation**

Suppose I had an interval $S = [a,b]\in\Bbb{R}$, then $$\mathrm{NOT}(S) = (-\infty,a) \cup (b,\infty)$$

**Quantum NOT operation**

$$\ket{\downarrow} =
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\ 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$\ket{\uparrow} =
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\ 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0\\
\end{bmatrix}
\ket{\downarrow} = \ket{\uparrow}$$

See [here](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_gate) for a source on how I defined the quantum NOT operation.

**My Confusion**

If I consider
$$\ket{\downarrow} =
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\ 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$
this is just one point of a set of all possible linear combinations of $a\ket{\uparrow} +b\ket{\downarrow}$. So then
$$\mathrm{NOT}(\ket{\downarrow})\neq \ket{\uparrow}$$ but instead would be a set of points.

**My Question**

Is the quantum NOT operation supposed to be similar to the classical NOT operation? Am I just misunderstanding the definition of the quantum NOT operation or is quantum logic somehow different from classical logic?

Answer (score 1):

$\renewcommand{ket}[1]{\left| #1 \right\rangle}$

In my question I was trying to define the $\mathrm{NOT}$ operation using set theory. I got confused because I regarded $ \mathrm{NOT}$ as mapping from points in $[a,b]$ onto points in $(-\infty,a,)\cup (b,\infty)$. This is wrong.

Let $X = [a,b]$ and let $Y = (-\infty,a,)\cup (b,\infty)$. Consider the set $S = \lbrace X,Y\rbrace$. $\mathrm{NOT}(X)$ maps from the *element* $X$ to the *element* $Y$. In other words, it is **not** a map from real numbers to real numbers but **a map from elements of a set $S$ to elements of a set $S$**. That is, $$\mathrm{NOT}: S \rightarrow S$$ So when $\mathrm{NOT}(X)$ acts on elements of $S$, it doesn't treat them like points in $\Bbb{R}$ but just as sets. So there is one and only one value for $\mathrm{NOT}(X)$ or $\mathrm{NOT}(Y)$ That is, $$\mathrm{NOT}(X) = Y$$
$$\mathrm{NOT}(Y)=X$$
So the key point here is, it isn't a map between points in $\Bbb{R}$ but instead a map between elements of $S$.

---

Let me now comment on $\mathrm{QNOT}$.

First, let us note $\mathrm{NOT}$ has two key properties

1. It is bijective.
2. It is an involution.

I will demonstrate $\mathrm{QNOT}$ has these properties.

Let $V$ be a complex vector space. Let $\alpha,\beta\in\Bbb{C}$. Let 
$$\ket{\downarrow} =
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\ 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$\ket{\uparrow} =
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\ 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$ \mathrm{QNOT}(\vec{v}):= \begin{bmatrix}
0 &1 \\ 1&0 \\
\end{bmatrix}\vec{v}$$

**Claim 1:** $\mathrm{QNOT}$ is an involution

**Reasoning:**
\begin{align*} \mathrm{QNOT}\left( \mathrm{QNOT}(\vec{v})\right)&= \begin{bmatrix}
0 &1 \\ 1&0 \\
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
0 &1 \\ 1&0 \\
\end{bmatrix}\vec{v}\\
&= \begin{bmatrix}
1 &0 \\ 0&1 \\
\end{bmatrix}\vec{v}\\
&=I_2 \vec{v}
\end{align*}

**Claim 2:**

For any given $\ket{\psi} = \alpha \ket{\uparrow} + \beta\ket{\downarrow} \in V$,  $\mathrm{QNOT}\left(\ket{\psi}\right)$ is bijective.

**Reasoning:**

As defined, $\mathrm{QNOT}$ is a linear operator acting on a vector $\ket{\psi} \in V$. In this case, from Claim 1, we can see $$\mathrm{QNOT} = \mathrm{QNOT}^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}
0 &1 \\ 1&0 \\
\end{bmatrix} $$

Thus, $\mathrm{QNOT}$ is has both a right and left inverse. Any matrix with both a right and left inverse is called an isomorphism and is also a bijection.

So the key point here is that, like $\mathrm{NOT}$, $\mathrm{QNOT}$

1. maps to one and only one element
2. can be applied again and get the original vector $\ket{\psi}$

I am not a quantum information theory expert, but to me that seems like a sensible enough argument to show why $\mathrm{NOT}$ and $\mathrm{QNOT}$ have similar properties.

Comment: In fact, the QNOT is similar to the NOT if you choose a particular basis and works exactly the same on may outputs, but it is not a true generalization of the not, as e.g. shown in the paper linked here: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/172232/what-sort-of-operations-can-be-applied-on-a-hilbert-spaces

Comment: Furthermore, I can write down many operations that have nothing to do with NOTs and yet fulfill properties 1. and 2. - e.g. the Pauli Y and Z-gates.

Comment: So is what I wrote wrong?

Comment: I mean, how would you define $\mathrm{NOT}$? I just stated a couple properties that seemed important to it.

Comment: I wasn't overly concerned with the classical NOT, I'm just saying that I don't think this is an appropriate characterization for quantum gates. Honestly, I find your definition of "NOT" confusing. Your QNOT is basically defined on qubits. Hence it should correspond to the classical NOT, which is a simple boolean function on bits: $NOT:\{0,1\}\to \{0,1\}$ defined the obvious way. It seems to me that you want to have a look at the logical NOT - but the QNOT is not equivalent to a logical NOT, also because quantum theory is not really based on boolean logic...